# PyQt: widget for listing by in clickable rows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am looking for a widget that would help me in building a GUI for a python program using PyQt5.

I need to display a list of data, row by row. When clicking on one of the rows it will open a a different window.

I have looked into `QLabel`, `QTableView` but they do not seem to do the job - in the sense having the right `signals`.

Is there any widget in the library that could help me or should I start building my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QListWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html) with the [`itemClicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) signal should be enough.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Since then I have implemented something using clickable `QLabel`s. I have just moved up to another bit of code but will look into your suggestion. Thank you for the input!